# Can I play Infamous First Light without spoiling the story of Second Son?

Tags: infamous-second-son

I have not played Second Son and know nothing about its story. I'm thinking about getting the standalone add-on First Light, but I was wondering if the stories of First Light and Second Son are completely separate or if First Light will contain spoilers to the story of Second Son. All I know is that the main character of First Light also appears in Second Son, so I feel that there is potential for story spoilers.

If there are spoilers, please don't tell me exactly what they are or put them in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, playing First Light will definitely give you foresight into the characters in the story of Second Son.

The plot of First Light follows Abigail, a supporting character in Second Son, up and to the point of the start of Second Son's storyline. And while you learn more detail her back story, in doing so you will have greater knowledge of the main antagonist of Second Son. And that is all I can say with out it being a spoiler so the rest goes in a tag.

> Brooke is the main antagonist in Second Son and from the get go of that story line she is just a clean-up and containment crew of conduits. By going through First Light it will be very clear that that is not what she is actually up to and could potentially ruin any reveals/twists in the first game.